# Predict and identify the coefficient of an exponential increasing function

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

I have done an experiment, by recording the input and the output data, I want to do an extrapolation (meaning predict the output of an input outside the observation region)

this is my input vector
x=[ 30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39    40    41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49    50];

this is my output vector
f(x)=y=[0.0100    0.0167    0.0267    0.0431    0.0642    0.1176    0.1756    0.2649    0.4333    0.7053    1.1629    1.8678    3.0025    4.9139    7.8152
12.5813   20.3237   32.5780   56.0082   86.4069  140.6530]

My questions is:

1. what is the mathimatical method to get the coefficintes A,B and C,if i suppose that my function (or input-output relation) is of the form

   $y=B^{x+A}+C$

Comment: It's probably easier to fit to $A\cdot B^x + C$. You can do this using least squares.

Comment: Equivalent but more "physical" would be $y=a e^{bx}+c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a first thing you could have done : if you plot $\log(y)$ as a function of $x$, the data are almost along a straight line. This means that, foolowing Tony S.F.'s suggestion, if the model you want to fit writes $$y=A\,B^x+C$$ you can start ignoring the $C$ term and get $$\log(y)=\alpha +\beta x$$ (using $\alpha=\log(A)$ and $\beta=\log(B)$). Parameters $\alpha,\beta$ are easily obtained using a standard [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). Doing it, you would find a very good fit ($R^2=0.999871$) $$\log(y)=-18.8916+0.476311 x$$ So, for $C=0$, $A=6.24428\times 10^{-9}$ and $B=1.61012$. Notice that this can very easily be done using Excel.

Now, since you have these estimates, you can start a [nonlinear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression) for the full model. This would lead to $$y= 5.86506\times 10^{-9}\times1.61287^x-0.0493574$$ ($R^2=0.999826$) and this looks, at first glance, quite fine. But you must look also at the standard errors and the confidence intervals for the parameters. In this case, you would notice that parameter $C$ is not statistically significant since its standard error is $0.1578$ and its confidence interval is
$\{-0.380883,0.282168\}$; all of that means that we can ignore $C$ in the model.

For the full model, the sum of squared errors is $5.59454$; rerunning the model without parameter $C$ gives $$y= 5.70154\times 10^{-9}\times1.61377^x$$ ($R^2=0.999825$) corresponding to a sum of squared errors equal to $5.62501$; as you can see, the contribution of $C$ was negligible.

Last point of interest : if you use the full model, the predicted value of $y$ would be negative for any $x < 33.36$ which, I suppose, does not mean anything.

I shall finish with a recommendation : since your data start at $x=30$, it would be better to scale the model as $$y=A \times B^{(x-30)}$$ This will not change anything to the results but would lead to more understandable parameters. In the cas of your data, it would result $$y=0.00980121 \times 1.61377^{(x-30)}$$

More "physical", as I wrote in a comment, would be $$y=0.00980121 e^{0.478576 (x-30)}$$

Comment: I just have a look and compared to the method of regression with integral equation which is of no practical interest in the present case because $C$ is quite negligable and there is no difficulty to guess the initial values to start the non-linear regression.  Cheers.